# Is there any way to manipulate embedded ppt slides with c#?

Tags: c#, object, powerpoint, ole

I want to embed a slide in a slide, which looks like just a picture when it's embedded, and I can double-click that to modify the iframe-like slide, and that will be stored in the original PPTX file with SLDX extension, not external PPTX file.

This is easy, I just go to Insert Menu, Object, and select new Powerpoint slide

But I want to reuse this slide, so that I can edit one and update the others. but copying the OLE objects makes a deep copied slide, and modification to the original one doesn't apply to copied one. I know embedding from external PPTX makes this easy. but I just want to store all embedded slides into the one original PPTX file

How do I SHALLOW COPY the OLE Objects..?

Comment: Hi, I will recommend reading [ask], and [mcve]. The last 4 sentenced make it look like you where talking to someone or answering my mental question. That's disturbing

Comment: thanks for the helpful comments, I just edited those disturbing monologue